# How can i return a list of images using Ilist<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

here is my code

```
        private IList<imagem> ListaImagem()
        {
            ArrayList img = new ArrayList();

            var imagens = from imagem in contexto.imagem
                          select new { 
                                       imagem.SRC, 
                                       imagem.TITULO 
                                     };
            return imagens.ToList();
        }
```

And this error apper:
CCannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'
 So I look in everywhere and nobody has an answer. What can i do?

Answer (score 7):

Your query currently selects the `SRC` and `TITULO` properties into an anonymous type. Are you sure you don't just need this?

```
private IList<imagem> ListaImagem()
{
    return contexto.imagem.ToList();
}
```

We don't really know anything about your `imagem` class or what `contexto.imagem` returns...  if the above doesn't work, please give us more information about what you're trying to do. I strongly suspect you *don't* want to use an anonymous type (which is what you get from `new { ... }`) in this case.